# How remove multiple spaces from old contacts?

Tags: integration, contact

I have a problem with integration when a contact have multiple spaces, I already did a validation rule to not save if has, but I desactivated and put on a trigger of before insert and update with a replaceAll that remove the multiple spaces, but the old contacts that already have the multiple spaces are not being treated, I can not do a update on the database, because is to big, and I don't see another solution besides insert the function that remove the spaces in every integration. There's another way?

Comment: For the existing data, can you export the data, remove the double spaces, and import it again? Doesn't your trigger automatically cover every double space scenario with every integration? Or do you have integrations that you allow to bypass triggers?

Comment: The integration do a select query on this contacts, and the occour an error, I can only prevent insert and update, not select.. And I can not import again, It has a lot of records

Comment: How many records are there? If you have can choose what field integration queries than you could store the original field value with the duplicate spaces separately before you clean the data.

Comment: I can't heaven create a field on standard objects.. it's a global org, we can not do this kinds of things.. but thank you

Comment: Without a lot more information about your situation and your restriction we're unlikely to be-able to help you find a solution. If you'd like you can edit your question to include more details

Answer (score 1):

For existing Contacts with repeated spaces, you have no choice but to go through the existing data.

### If you have fewer than 50 million Contacts

- You can write a batch job that queries the Contacts in the `start()` method
- In the `execute()` method, you can update the Contacts that have the multiple spaces

### If you have more than 50 million Contacts

- Same as above except use runtime parameters to limit the number of rows by `Contact.CreatedDate`, for example, by year, or year-month
- Run the batch job multiple times

### Or - BulkAPI

You could also use the BulkAPI and process the fetched Contacts externally before updating them back in the database